# Redbean: How to use R::graph() with json decoded input

Tags: redbean

I *think* I'm using Redbean 3.3.7 (the all-in-one download from the website), but I can't find a version number in the code.
I am receiving some json encoded data and want to process it with R::graph(), but I'm getting an error.

```
$json = '{"id": "","title": "Test Article","slug": "test-article","content": "<p>This is a test article</p>"}';

$decoded = json_decode($json, true);
```

This gives me an array

```
var_dump($decoded)

array(4) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["title"]=>
  string(12) "Test Article"
  ["slug"]=>
  string(12) "test-article"
  ["content"]=>
  string(29) "<p>This is a test article</p>"
}
```

Also

```
echo gettype($decoded);
```

returns "array".

But when I try this:

```
$bean = R::graph($decoded);
```

I get a RedBean_Exception_Security error with the message "Expected array but got :string";
rb.php line 9029

What am I doing wrong?
And more importantly, how do I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: OK two seconds after I asked this question I found the answer. My rep is < 50 so I couldn't just add it as an answer. According to the documentation "An array has to contain a key named 'type' containing the type of bean it represents". So I just had to add   $decoded['type'] = 'articles' before calling R::graph().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation "An array has to contain a key named 'type' containing the type of bean it represents". So I just had to add $decoded['type'] = 'table_name' before calling R::graph(). It also works if I add a hidden field named 'type' in the form I submit.

```
<input type="hidden" name="type" value="table_name" />
```